# Sentry 9 YouTrack Plugin Compatibility Issue

Tags: sentry, youtrack

It seems like `sentry-youtrack` plugin is not fully compatible with the latest Sentry 9 version. I've discovered at least three issues:

1. Tricky combination of `redis-py-cluster` and `redis`: latest versions seems to be not compatible with each over out of the box.
2. Creation of new issues is broken due to absence of `sentry/groups/details.html` file.
3. The list of projects on YouTrack is not populated, therefore a project in Sentry can't be liked to a project in YouTrack.

I've created an issue in the repository of the plugin: https://github.com/bogdal/sentry-youtrack/issues/26, but the latest release was issued almost 2 years ago, therefore, I'm not sure this will be solved quickly. Maybe there workarounds or alternative solutions known by the community.